# Continuous-time RNN and Shannon sampling theorem

Tags: sampling, continuous-signals, machine-learning

The most-used discrete-time RNN equations used in Deep Learning these days are those of Elman:
[image]

I have seen two very different continuous-time version of these, with different justifications. The most "natural" to me are the leaky integrator onces (here sigmoid is replaced with tanh, but any activation function would do):

[image]

which is justified by saying that taylor expanding this equation with discretization step of 1 gives back the discrete time equations above [(see this)](http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/chrono.pdf).

Another version is found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network#Continuous-time) (notice how the weight is outside the activation function!)

[image]

and justified by saying

> Note that, by the Shannon sampling theorem, discrete time recurrent neural networks can be viewed as continuous-time recurrent neural networks where the differential equations have transformed into equivalent difference equations. This transformation can be thought of as occurring after the post-synaptic node activation functions $y_{i}(t)$ have been low-pass filtered but prior to sampling.

Could someone explain this?